# What is the "Tangle" at the Heart of Quantum Simulation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-computation, simulation

The following questions generalize and naturalize the question that was originally asked.  Provisional answers largely due to [Will Sawin](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/143624/revisions) are now included.

As was discussed in the question originally asked, let $$\mathcal{L}(r,\{a_i\})\ {\colon}{=}\ \sigma_r\big(\text{Seg}(\mathbb{P}^{a_1-1}\times\cdots\times\mathbb{P}^{a_n-1})\big) \subset \ \mathbb{P}^{(\Pi_{i=1}^n a_i) -1}$$ be the usual Segre immersion of the rank-$r$ secant join. Regarding $\mathbb{P}^{(\Pi_{i=1}^n a_i) -1}$ as an $n$-qudit Hilbert space denoted $\mathcal{H}$ for concision, and furthermore regarding $\mathcal{H}$ as a Kähler manifold, we specify $\omega$ on $\mathcal{L}$ as the symplectic form associated to the Kähler potential $\kappa = \langle\psi|\psi\rangle$, given first as a real-valued (bilinear/biholomorphic) function $\kappa\colon \mathcal{H}\to\mathbb{R}$, and thus specified as $\kappa\colon \mathcal{L}\to\mathbb{R}$ by pullback onto the Segre immersion $\mathcal{L}\subset\mathcal{H}$; similarly let $g=\langle\psi|G|\psi\rangle$ be the real-valued (bilinear/biholomorphic) symbol function that is specified by a general hermitian operator $G$, with $g$ similarly pulled-back to $\mathcal{L}$ from  $\mathcal{H}$.

Answers to these questions (or better-constructed questions) were sought:

> **Q1**  Is the Zariski closure of $\mathcal{L}(r,\{a_i\})$ endowed with a differential structure that is globally smooth?
>
> **A1**  The answer is no (not in general).  For example (as explained by Will Sawin) the manifolds $\mathcal{L}(a-1,\{a,a\})$ are determinantal, and thus are known to be generously endowed with singular points.
>
> ===
>
> **Q2**  In the event that $\mathcal{L}$ is equipped with (one or more) smooth differential structure(s), is it the case that $dg \in \text{span}\ \hat\omega$?  Physically, are hermitian operators on $\mathcal{H}$ generically associated to singularity-free symplectomorphic flows on differentially smooth immersed $\mathcal{L}$-manifolds?
>
> **A2**  Formally the answer is no, in that $\mathcal{L}$ generically has no smooth differential structure, per answer **A1**.
>
> ===
>
> **Q3**  In the event that $\mathcal{L}$ has no defect-free differential structure(s), what smoothness-defects appear in the symplectomorphic flows on $\mathcal{L}$ that are induced by pullback of (bilinear/biholomorphic) Hamiltonian potential functions from $\mathcal{H}$?
>
> **A3**  Despite the algebraic singularities that are mentioned in **A1–2**, the answer is conjectured to be "symplectic defects are dynamically occult", in a concrete sense that will be explained in an auxiliary answer (to be posted in the next day or two).  In brief, the Hamiltonian structure that is pulled back from $\mathcal{H}$ is conjectured to induce dynamical maps $M(t)\colon \mathcal{L}\to\mathcal{L}$ that are exact symplectic isomormorphisms, despite the singular points of $\mathcal{L}$, and despite the rank-deficit of the pulled-back symplectic form $\omega$ at those singular points.  Physically speaking this, means that the varietal singularities of $\mathcal{L}$ do not obstruct computational simulations of thermodynamical physics associated to symplectomorphic dynamical flow.

**Engineering motivation**  Engineers "know" — from concrete computations — that $\mathcal{L}$ is richly endowed with singularities in Riemannian/Ricci/scalar curvature.  And yet experience teaches that these curvature singularities are seldom (never?) associated to computational pathologies in simulating quantum trajectories as integral curves of Hamiltonian flows.   Thus the questions asked are motivated by a postulate that the structure of $\mathcal{L}$ is differentially smooth with respect to symplectic forms and Hamiltonian potentials that are pulled-back from $\mathcal{H}$, even though $\mathcal{H}$ induces metric curvature on $\mathcal{L}$ that is singular.

**The broad question**  In what mathematical sense(s) — if any — does algebraic geometry teach that $\mathcal{L}$'s symplectic geometry is differentially smooth, even though  $\mathcal{L}$'s metric geometry is singular?  In purely practical terms, why don't our quantum trajectory simulation codes break more often? Advice in framing these questions more clearly and naturally is very welcome.

---

**The questions originally asked**  The questions asked concern one-dimensional closed-loop submanifolds of Hilbert space called *LangreTangles*.  The specific questions asked are:

1. What is the large-$n$ probability $P(n)$ that an $n$-dimensional Hilbert space supports LangreTangle trajectories?
2. What is the large-$n$ length $l(n)$ of a generic LangreTangle trajectory?

Numerical evidence suggests $P(n) \gtrsim 5/(\ln n)$  and  $\ln l(n)\sim \mathcal{O}(n)$.

In physical terms LangreTangles are emergently-quantum trajectories on "foamy" dynamical manifolds; thus natural physics-oriented questions include "What experimental techniques are suited to the observation of LangreTangle trajectories?"

[image: image of a LangreTangle trajectory]

*Caption*  A numerically-integrated portion of a typical LangreTangle trajectory $L(\psi_0,4,\{3,3,3\})$, drawn as a projective map $S^3\,{\to}\,R^3$.  It is conjectured that the full LangreTangle would fill $R^3$ with a closed-loop "tangle".  Physically this particular LangreTangle is associated to the rank-$4$ secant join of the product state of three spin-$1$ particles. Further LangreTangles have been computed as follows:

1. a full (closed-loop) LangreTangle for the simplest-of-all determinantal varieties $\mathcal{L}(1,\{2,2\})$ ( [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXGGe.jpg) );
2. a partial LangreTangle for the determinantal variety $\mathcal{L}(4,\{5,5\})$ ( [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xG7LN.jpg) )
3. a partial LangreTangle for the unit-zabacity (is it nondeterminantal?) variety $\mathcal{L}(9,\{2,2,2,2,2,2\})$ ( [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j79Qk.jpg) ); this is an example of a nontrivial unit-zabacity variety that is nondefective in the sense of Landsberg.

---

**Remark**  The $\mathcal{L}(a-1,\{a,a\})$ representation of determinantal varieties is defective for all $a\gt2$, and the $\mathcal{L}(4,\{3,3,3\})$ variety of the original question is defective also; the latter by a result of Strassen per [Landsberg](http://books.google.com/books?id=JTjv3DTvxZIC&pg=PR17) p. 130.

**Background**  With reference to a recent much-discussed preprint *Scattering Amplitudes and the Positive Grassmannian( by Nima Arkani-Hamed, Jacob L. Bourjaily, Freddy Cachazo, Alexander B. Goncharov, Alexander Postnikov, and Jaroslav Trnka ([arXiv:1212.5605 [hep-th]](http://arxiv.org/abs/1212.5605)), coauthor Arkani-Hamed asserted the following research objective in an associated lecture [*The Amplituhedron*](http://susy2013.ictp.it/video/05_Friday/2013_08_30_Arkani-Hamed_4-3.html):

> We can't just keep making equivalences between ideas that were essentially handed to us from the early part of the 20th century.  We have to find really new things!

As a conjectural candidate for "a really new thing," Arkani-Hamed *et al.*  describe a class of non-Hilbert dynamical systems in which unitarity and locality are encoded emergently, in geometric objects called *amplituhedrons* — for details see Gil Kalai's *MathOverflow* question "[What is the amplituhedron?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/143339/what-is-the-amplituhedron)" — that have been depicted in the non-specialist literature as "[a jewel at the heart of quantum physics](https://www.simonsfoundation.org/quanta/20130917-a-jewel-at-the-heart-of-quantum-physics/)"

**Engineering considerations**  Quantum systems engineers are naturally sympathetic to the notion of dynamical systems in which unitarity and spatial locality are emergent rather than fundamental, in that large-scale quantum systems commonly are simulated by algorithms in which unitarity is only approximate (in that trajectories are integrated on non-Hilbert tensor network manifolds) and spatial locality is emergent (via Lindblad/Carmichael trajectory unravelings that dynamically quench macroscopic Schröedinger cats).

**Nomenclature**  To concretely visualize these non-Hilbert quantum trajectories, we adopt the notation of Robert Landsberg's text [*Tensors: Geometry and Applications*](http://books.google.com/books?id=JTjv3DTvxZIC&pg=PR17), in which the geometric objects of primary interest are *secant varieties of Segre varieties*

$$
\mathcal{L}(r,\{a_i\}) \equiv 
\sigma_r\big(\text{Seg}(\mathbb{P}^{a_1-1}\times\cdots\times\mathbb{P}^{a_n-1})\big) \subset \mathbb{P}^{(\Pi_{i=1}^n a_i) -1}
$$

Here the manifold $\mathcal{L}(r,\{a_i\})$ is regarded as Segre-embedded in a Hilbert space of (normalized) states $\mathbb{P}^{(\Pi_{i=1}^n a_i)-1}$.  Then the *zabacity* function $\text{zab}(r,\{a_i\})$ is defined to be the dimensional deficit

$$
\text{zab}(r,\{a_i\}) = \big((\Pi_{i=1}^n a_i)-1\big) - \dim \mathcal{L}(r,\{a_i\})
$$

**Unit-zabacity manifolds**  Henceforth we focus our attention upon unit-zabacity manifolds (that is, $\text{zab}(r,\{a_i\})=1$).  Physically these are tensor network manifolds that *almost* fill the embedding Hilbert space, being dimensionally deficient by precisely *one* complex dimension, which is to say, deficient by precisely *two* real dimensions.  Among the most celebrated unit-zabacity manifolds is $\mathcal{L}(4,\{3,3,3\})$ (see for example [Theorem 5.5.2.1 of Landsberg's text](http://books.google.com/books?id=JTjv3DTvxZIC&pg=PA128)) which physically is the rank-$4$ secant join of the product state of three spin-$1$ particles.

**Visualizing unit-zabacity geometry**  The geometry of $\mathcal{L}(4,\{3,3,3\})$, regarded as a submanifold of complex dimension 25 immersed in a normalized Hilbert space $\mathbb{P}^{3^3-1}$ of dimension $3^3-1=26$, can be concretely visualized by intersecting $\mathcal{L}(4,\{3,3,3\})$ with any convenient three-dimensional submanifold of the immersing $\mathbb{P}^{3^3-1}$ Hilbert space; an obvious and geometrically natural candidate for such a three-dimensional submanifold is the rotation group $\text{SO}(3)\sim S^3$.  Then we have:

> **Definition**  The *LangreTangle trajectory* $L(\psi_0,r,\{a_i\})$ that is associated to a unit-zabacity manifold $\mathcal{L}(r,\{a_i\})$, and to a fiducial point $p_0\in \mathcal{L}(r,\{a_i\})$, with $\psi(p_0)=\psi_0$, is by definition the one-dimensional submanifold of points $q\in S^3$ such that the rotated state $\psi(q)= R(q)\circ\psi_0$ satisfies $\psi(q) = \psi(p)$ for some $p\in \mathcal{L}(r,\{a_i\})$.

**Numerical and graphical considerations**  Closed-form arbitrary-dimension representations of the quantum rotation matrix $R(q)$ (which are due to Wigner) are given in standard textbooks such as Gottfried's *Quantum Mechanics* (1966); quaternionic coordinates on $S^3$ are well-suited to efficient trajectory integration; graphical representations of the [Hopf fibration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_fibration) commonly employ the simple-to-compute projective map $S^3\to R^3$; thus the exhibition of concrete LangreTangle trajectories is computationally straightforward.

**LangreTangled trajectories**  For generic starting-states $\psi_0$, numerical integration of the LangreTangle trajectories for $L(\psi_0,4,\{3,3,3\})$ shows a striking "tangle", and higher-dimension unit-zabicity manifolds (not shown) are found to support even more tightly tangled trajectories. This tangled geometry motivates both the name of the *zabacity* dimension-measure (from the Persian *zabd* meaning "foam-like," and *zubdat* meaning "cream-like," as skimmed from a body of liquid) and the [portmanteau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau#Origin) word *LangreTangle*, which derives from "Robert LANdsberg" and "Corrado SeGRE*" and "quantum enTANGLEment".

**Open questions**  The questions asked in the beginning then follow naturally from the preceding considerations (along with many more mathematical questions, needless to say).  In particular, the strikingly high prevalence of unit-zabicity large-dimension Hilbert spaces apparently is associated to the numeric properties of [Cunningham numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cunningham_project), which cause unit-zabacity Hilbert spaces of large dimension to be exponentially more common than heuristic factor-counting arguments would suggest (in that, for [various number-theoretic reasons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cunningham_project#Factors_of_Cunningham_numbers), the Cunningham integers $a^b\pm 1$ commonly have small factors); the question-asker would be grateful for mathematical illumination in regard to this connexion.

**Physics perspectives**  From a physics perspective, a natural question is simply: "By what observations, either in principle or in practice, can (flat) Hilbert-space dynamical manifolds be experimentally distinguished from ("foamy") finite-zabacity dynamical manifolds, even for systems as simple (seemingly) as three interacting spin-$1$ particles?" Again, references and/or experimental suggestions are welcome.

---

**Acknowledgements**  The continuing stimulus of [comments](http://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=1537#comment-88047) and [questions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/143339/what-is-the-amplituhedron) by Gil Kalai]in regard to issues of quantum unitarity, locality, and algebraic geometry is gratefully acknowledged.

Comment: The image is stunning! Can it be understood without reference to $\mathcal{L}(\psi_0,4,\{3,3,3\})$? How was it generated?

Comment: Joseph, the sphere is a Mathematica "ParametricPlot3D" object (in Riemann coordinates) and the Langretangle trajectory is several thousand Mathematica "Tube[BezierCurve[#[[i]],SplineDegree -> 3],0.0225]&" graphics objects (plus fiddling with lighting, etc.).  The L(4,{3,3,3}) figure shows only a fraction of what is (we think) effectively a manifold-filling curve and the larger-dimension 6-qubit L(9,{2,2,2,2,2,2}) Langretangle trajectories are far "foamier" even than the 3-qutrit example shown.  Systems of 16, 30, 306, 1020, 65536, and 134,217,756 qubits too are unit-zabadicity Hilbert spaces.

Comment: +1 for awesome detail and questions.  I would give +more if I could.

Comment: Thank you Theo.  Our UW Quantum Systems Engineering group uses finite-zabacity manifolds to validate large-n quantum simulations of thermometric transport processes.  As our mathematical understanding of finite-zabacity dynamical systems has increased, we are finding more-and-more commonly that the large numerical calculations are dispensable, because finite-zabacity validation tests *themselves* suffice for many practical quantum transport engineering purposes.

Comment: What do you mean by the probability that a Hilbert space has a certain property? Isn't there one Hilbert space of each finite dimension? Do you mean to take a random dimension in some interval, or is there some other structure on the Hilbert space that I'm not seeing?

Comment: Will Sawin, thank you for these questions. The bounty questions Q1-3 apply (hopefully!) to all finite-dimensional Hilbert spaces H in which a rank-r secant variety of a Segre variety L is immersed. The LangreTangle trajectories of the original question can be appreciated as specific examples of quantum dynamical trajectories on L, in that a concrete LangreTangle curve is the closed-loop quantum dynamical trajectory that is associated to a concrete time-dependent Hamiltonian potential; that potential being constructed such that the LangreTangle curve can be represented as a trajectory in S3.

Comment: Will Sawin, the phrasing of the question now has been tuned to clarify the issues that you raised.  Thank you again.

Comment: Will Sawin asks: "What do you mean by the probability that a Hilbert space has a certain property?" This question is well-posed in a number-theoretic sense.  Consider a n-qudit Hilbert space of d-dimensional qudits; the associated projective manifold has dimension d^n-1.  For fixed d and large n, what is the asymptotic probability that there exists a secant variety of Segre varieties whose dimension is d^n-2? Naive factor-counting suggests that this probability will be O(1/n), but experiments indicate a larger probability O(1/ln(n)).  Results from the Cunningham Project suggest reasons why.

Comment: Dear John, thanks for mentioning me! your question seems very interesting but loaded with so many new notions, ideas, concepts, sub-questions, and connections,that it make it hard for me  to understand. I suppose that the crucial thing to understand is your underlined definition of the "LangreTangle trajectory." Right?

Comment: Gil I have added a link to your fine *MathOverflow* question "[What is the amplituhedron?](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/143339/what-is-the-amplituhedron)".  It will be a long time (as it seems to me) before we appreciate even good questions to ask, much less discover good answers.  Our UW QSE group's starting question is purely practical: why don't curvature singularities on Kahlerian algebraic varieties break quantum trajectory integrations?  Questions Q1-3 explore the postulated answer "Because the symplectic geometry is smooth."  We wish we understood these questions/answers better!

Comment: @John: does there exist a preprint/article of yours that gives more mathematical details related to your question, or puts it in context ?

Comment: If a Hilbert space admits more than one Segre variety, do you wish to ask whether the distinct Segre varieties have secant varieties that are hypersurfaces, or count the $n$-dimensional Hilbert space as having a unit-zabacity trajectory as long as just one of its factorizations has such a secant variety?

Comment: Will Sawin, in practice we increase the rank of the secant join whenever Hamiltonian interactions make trajectories "more quantum"; similarly we decrease the rank whenever Lindbladian noise makes trajectories less quantum. Regrettably these rank-adjustments are decided by principles that are entirely *ad hoc*. That is why we would be very grateful for *any* more rigorous mathematical insights into the symplectic state-space geometries that we are dealing with, with a concrete view toward systematically improving the accuracy, efficiency, and reliability of our trajectory integrations.

Comment: **Piyush Grover** asks "Does there exist a preprint/article of yours that gives more mathematical details".  We are writing such an article, and texts like Robert Landsberg's *Tensors: Geometry and Applications* are very helpful.  But alas,  engineering-level discussions of the metric/symplectic geometry of varietal state-spaces are not found in *any* texts (that are known to us).  That is why most of what we "know" comes from numerical experience, and why that "knowledge" is very far from rigorous or complete.  That is why guides to the algebraic geometry literature are *very* welcome.

Comment: What Hamiltonians do you use specifically? Could the nonsingularity of the flow be related to some feature of the Hamiltonian?

Comment: Yes, further numerical investigations (backed by nascent algebraic confirmation) suggest that Hamiltonian trajectories "steer clear" of singular points of $\mathcal{L}$, in a certain technical sense, for reasons that are mentioned as the conjectured answer to Q3.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\mathcal L(a-1,\{a,a\})$ is the hypersurface of the determinant $0$ matrices in the rank $a \times a$. I'm afraid that this hypersurface is not a topological manifold, and hence also not a smooth one.

To see this, it is sufficient to look in a small neighborhood of a rank $a-2$ matrix. Were the  hypersurface a manifold, that space would have to be topologically a ball, as we see in the neighborhood of a cuspidal curve singularity like the singularity $(x,y,z) = (0,0,1)$ of $y^2z-x^3=0$.  However, our neighborhood will not be a ball.

The topology of an algebraic variety in the neighborhood of a  point is determined only by the leading terms of the polynomial equation that cuts it out. In the neighborhood of the point:

$\left(\begin{array}{cccccc} 1 & 0 &  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0  &  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 &  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array}\right)$

(here depicted with $a=6$) the leading terms come are the terms involving all $a-2$ nonzero entries. Since there is one term for each permutation, there are only two leading terms : the identity permutation and the transposition of the last two entries.

This means that locally, the hypersurface looks like the equation $x_1x_2-x_3x_4$ in the variables $x_1,x_2,\dots, x_{a^2-1}$, where $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$, $x_4$ are the entries of the bottom-right $2 \times 2$ submatrix. The vanishing set of the equation $x_1 x_2 -x_3x_4$ in just the variables $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ is topologically isomorphic to the cone on an $S^1$ bundle on $S^2 \times S^2$, which is the cone on a non-sphere, so is not a topological manifold. Since we can detect this failure homologically, adding more variables, which just corresponds to taking the product with $\mathbb R^{2(a^2-5)}$, does not make it a manifold.

Comment: Will Sawin, thank you. Your examples are known to us (they are line 1 of the table associated to the above-referenced [Theorem 5.5.2.1 of Landsberg's text](http://books.google.com/books?id=JTjv3DTvxZIC&pg=PR17), for example). It is easy to characterize their curvature singularities, which are located on the Zariski completions, but it is *not* so easy to characterize these Zariski/curvature singularities via defects in symplectomorphic flows. Physically these manifolds (apparently) are compatible with  thermodynamics: what dynamics are associated to "detecting this failure homologically?"

Comment: I will mention too, that a possible distinction between the L's topological structure and L's differential structure--in particular that there might be subtleties associated to symplectic realizations of the latter---was first suggested by the unanticipated robustness of our Hamiltonian trajectory integrator near curvature singularities; then suggested again (less rigorously) by the "twisty" rotations of the LangreTangle construction, which called to mind the "twisty" constructions of [Milnor's exotic spheres](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_sphere#Explicit_examples_of_exotic_spheres)

Comment: And finally, is it evident that $\text{dim}\,\mathcal{L}(a-1,\{a,a\}) \lt \text{dim}\,\mathbb{P}^{a^2-1}$, which is to say, that your large-$a$ examples of $\mathcal{L}$ are small enough (dimensionally) to immerse in $\mathcal{H}$?

Comment: Will Sawin, thank you very much for suggesting the 2-qudit test case!  In a preliminary test, our codes integrated $\mathcal{L}(a-1,\{a,a\})$ LangreTangles for the case $a=5$ without encountering obstructions. So I will run a few more cases tonight, and hopefully tomorrow provide some graphical examples (it's more work to draw the nice 3D graphics than to integrate the raw trajectory). It really is quite a mystery (to us) why the integration code does not encounter  singularities.  Thank you again for this example.

Comment: What integral, specifically, is the integration code integrating?

Comment: I've finished integrating LangreTangles for $a\in \{2,3,4,5\}$.  To forestall nomenclature confusion, in regard to the $a=2$ case in particular, the embedding space $\mathbb{P}^3$ is equipped with coordinate functions $\{ \psi_1,\psi_2,\psi_3,\psi_4 \}$, such that (in your language) the "vanishing set" of the determinantal variety $\psi_1\psi_4 - \psi_2 \psi_3$ is parametrized by us engineers as two Bloch spheres, or in your language $S^2\times S^2$. We engineers regard Bloch product spaces as free of singularities; are they nonetheless non-manifolds (possibly for some technical reason)?

Comment: My argument that singularities exist only applies for $a>2$.

Comment: Uh-oh, in the words of [Edmund BlackAdder](http://www.thetop100.net/the-entertainment-zone/the-top-100-blackadder-quotes/list/z26l54.aspx) "I sense Zariski closure creeping this way."

Comment: Will Sawin, the question has been edited to begin with your (excellent) suggestion of studying determinantal manifolds as test case, and the associated LangreTangle images are visually pleasing.  Further comments from you (or anyone) in regard to the symplectic structure of the singularities of determinantal varieties would be very welcome; empirically the symplectic geometry of determinantal singularities is of such a nature that our trajectory integrations are not obstructed by them.

Comment: Will Sawin, further investigations/reading affirm that the $\mathcal{L}$-sets: (1) viewed as varieties have singular points; and (2) viewed as metric manifolds have curvature singularities.  Indeed these two kinds of singularities coincide, and our curve-integrator codes throw exceptions when curves intersect these singularities.  Yet empirically the integrator codes *don't* throw exceptions; neither is there any very evident (to us) *symplectic* measure of proximity to singularities.  Thus a still-open question is "Why are varietal singularities symplectically and thermodynamically occult?"

Comment: It may help to appreciate too that engineers and scientists are catholic in their coordinate functions.  See for example Stoica's [*Schwarzschild Singularity is Semi-Regularizable*](http://arxiv.org/abs/1111.4837) (2011), also the more breezy Fromholz, Poisson, and Will article [*The Schwarzschild metric: It's the coordinates, stupid!*](http://arxiv.org/abs/1308.0394) (2013). In engineering, trajectory ensembles serve to estimate thermodynamical transport properties, hence algebraic/metric defects are of less concern than symplectomorphic defects ... which mysteriously are occult. Why is this?

Comment: Will Sawin, barring surprises you will receive the bounty tomorrow.  Further remarks are welcome in regard to distinguishing algebraic singularities vs metric singularities vs symplectic singularities.  Algebraic singularities are well-covered in (for example) John Milnor's *Singular points of complex hypersurfaces* (1968) and metric singularities in John Lee's *Riemannian manifolds: an introduction to curvature*. However no references regarding varietal symplectic singularities are yet known (to me); these are crucial to the entropic properties of symplectic trajectory integrations.

Comment: This is a stupid question, but could it simply be that the curves are avoiding the singularites? Since in the determinantal case the singular subset has complex codimension 3 / real codimension 6, a trajectory encountering it is unlikely.

Comment: Will Sawin, I'm drafting an auxiliary answer that discusses that question, namely, when Hamiltonian trajectories evade varietal singularities, is this by chance or by geometry? More rigorously, for $h$ a Hamiltonian potential and $\omega$ a pulled-back symplectic form, so that $\omega\llcorner X = dh$ specifies a Hamiltonian flow $X$ at regular points, does the induced map $M_X(t)\colon\mathcal{L}\to\mathcal{L}$ extend naturally to the singular points of $\mathcal{L}$ as a symplectomorphism, both abstractly and concretely (so trajectory integrations don't break thermodynamic relations)?

Comment: Thank you Will Sawin!  Yours is the bounty (and I notice that you have converted your answer to community wiki).  I hope to post my own (emerging) answer to **Q3** in the next day or so.  Thank you especially for helping to open my eyes to the vast---terrifying vast---mathematical literature on the geometry of varietal singularities.